# How to fix Duplicate instance declaration error in byron-spec-ledger package?

Tags: wallet, haskell

I'm trying to add `cardano-wallet-core` as a dependency to my Haskell project, so I can use the servant client. But I get this error when cabal builds the `byron-spec-ledger` package:

```
[ 6 of 16] Compiling Byron.Spec.Ledger.Update ( src/Byron/Spec/Ledger/Update.hs, dist/build/Byron/Spec/Ledger/Update.o, dist/build/Byron/Spec/Ledger/Update.dyn_o )

src/Byron/Spec/Ledger/Update.hs:236:10: error:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Hashable a => Hashable (Set a)
        -- Defined at src/Byron/Spec/Ledger/Update.hs:236:10
      instance Hashable v => Hashable (Set v)
        -- Defined in `hashable-1.3.4.1:Data.Hashable.Class'
    |
236 | instance Hashable a => Hashable (Set a) where
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Failed to build byron-spec-ledger-0.1.0.0 (which is required by
```

My `cabal.project` looks like this: https://pastebin.com/swdJWBAK

Using GHC 8.10.4.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that in `hashable-1.3.4.0`, the instance was added, and it [was also defined in the `byron-spec-ledger` package](https://input-output-hk.github.io/ouroboros-network/byron-spec-ledger/src/Byron.Spec.Ledger.Update.html#local-6989586621679556982).

Adding this constraint to my `cabal.project` file solved the issue:

```
constraints:
    hashable < 1.3.4.0
```