# Cannot build cardano-wallet-2021-12-15

Tags: wallet, cabal, build

I'm trying to build `cardano-wallet` with cabal. However, it fails wit the following error:

```
[19 of 20] Compiling Cardano.Ledger.TxIn ( src/Cardano/Ledger/TxIn.hs, dist/build/Cardano/Ledger/TxIn.o, dist/build/Cardano/Ledger/TxIn.dyn_o )

src/Cardano/Ledger/TxIn.hs:108:12: error:
    Not in scope: ‘HS.viewHash32’
    Module ‘Cardano.Crypto.Hash.Class’ does not export ‘viewHash32’.
    |
108 |       case HS.viewHash32 (extractHash sh) of
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/Cardano/Ledger/TxIn.hs:109:9: error:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘HS.ViewHashNot32’
    Module ‘Cardano.Crypto.Hash.Class’ does not export ‘ViewHashNot32’.
    |
109 |         HS.ViewHashNot32 -> TxInCompactOther tid (fromIntegral index)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/Cardano/Ledger/TxIn.hs:110:9: error:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘HS.ViewHash32’
    Module ‘Cardano.Crypto.Hash.Class’ does not export ‘ViewHash32’.
    |
110 |         HS.ViewHash32 a b c d -> TxInCompact32 a b c d (fromIntegral index)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/Cardano/Ledger/TxIn.hs:118:38: error:
    Not in scope: ‘HS.unsafeMkHash32’
    Module ‘Cardano.Crypto.Hash.Class’ does not export ‘unsafeMkHash32’.
    |
118 |     tid = TxId (unsafeMakeSafeHash $ HS.unsafeMkHash32 a b c d)
    |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Failed to build cardano-ledger-core-0.1.0.0 (which is required by
test:unit from cardano-wallet-core-2021.12.15, exe:local-cluster from
cardano-wallet-2021.12.15 and others). See the build log above for details.
```

I've found a [solution for similar error](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4534/how-to-fix-duplicate-instance-declaration-error-in-byron-spec-ledger-package) but adding the constraint of `hashable < 1.3.4.0` doesn't change anything.

Has anyone succeeded with a cabal build?

Answer (score 1):

Recommended way to build cardano-wallet is with stack. Check out this manual:

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet

I tried to build wallet recently and it was successful. Let me know if you will still have issues building it with stack. Cheers!